# Who is the "lead booker" of an Easyjet flight?

Tags: bookings, cancellations, refunds, easyjet

I'm trying to claim an Easyjet refund for cancelled flights due to COVID-19. The form asks for the "lead booker's name". I have two bookings with 6 persons on each flight, all booked through my e-mail address but paid for with one of the passenger's credit card.

Is the "lead booker" the first named passenger on the booking? Or the credit card holder? Or me because we used my e-mail address to book?

Comment: This is probably something you need to ask Easyjet, there isnt going to be an industry wide answer to your question - its company specific.

Comment: Someone on this site might know it though.

Comment: I suspect you're dramatically overthinking this. Who booked the flights? That's the name you use.

Answer (score 3):

The lead booker is the person who booked the flights. This can be:

- the holder of the EasyJet account used to login to perform the transaction, if any
- the holder of the main email address to which the booking confirmation and boarding passes were sent

I reached this conclusion by reading the [EasyJet terms and conditions](https://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions):

> #### Payment
>
> 4.7 Unless we tell you otherwise, the Booker must pay in full at the time of making your Booking.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Method of refund
>
> 5.5 We will only pay refunds to the Booker using the original payment method. If the original payment method is no longer available, we will refund to an alternative payment method in the Booker’s name. If you have booked through an Agent, they will be responsible for passing on any refund to you. We are not responsible for any fees the Agent may apply for processing the refund.
>
> 5.6 A refund made to someone presenting themselves to us as the Booker using the necessary Booking and security details, and who we reasonably believe is the Booker, will be deemed a proper refund and we will not process any further claim for a refund by the Booker or any other Passenger on the Booking.

From the wording it appears that the payment method used does not seem to matter. It is the person who made the booking that is responsible for paying, and claiming the refund.

Anyway, I would not worry about this. You made the booking and you are responsible for it. Therefore, you are authorised to cancel it.